# How to put the Google Adwords Conversion Tracking Pixel in OpenCart 3.x

Tags: php, opencart-3

I would like to put the adwords conversion pixel code in OpenCart 3.x on the checkout success page.

How can i insert the code in the header of the checkout success page only?

Many thanks.

I tried searching the stackoverflow site and the opencart forums, but no straight forward answer is provided anywhere.

```
<!-- Event snippet for conversion page -->
<script>
  gtag('event', 'conversion', {
      'send_to': 'XYZ12345',
      'transaction_id': ''
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the route is being passed from the controller to the header template and then in the header template write your Google code in this:

```
<?php if ($data['route'] == 'checkout/success') { ?>

    <!-- Event snippet for conversion page -->
    <script>
      gtag('event', 'conversion', {
          'send_to': 'XYZ12345',
          'transaction_id': ''
      });
    </script>

<?php } ?>
```

You'll also have to output correct values for "send_to" and "transaction_id".

Comment: Thank you, but can you kindly provide the code and location for the controller file?

Comment: Are you asking for programming help or asking for someone to do all the work for you? StackOverflow isn't a place to get free tasks done.